# Update status with interval

Tags: javascript

i trying create interval for updating status, but return in console log:

> Undefined

I need return status updated for every 100 miliseconds

My code:

```js
(function() {
  var status = 'Working...';

  if (document.getElementById('label_s').style.display === 'none') {
    status = 'Stopped.';
  } else {
    status = 'Reading label_s...';
    var labels = document.getElementById('label_s').innerHTML;
  }

  if (document.getElementById('label_d').style.display === 'none') {
    status = 'Stopped.';
  } else {
    status = 'Reading label_d...';
    var labelsd = document.getElementById('label_d').innerHTML;
  }

  status = 'Stopping';

  //UPDATE STATUS
  setInterval(updatestatus, 100);
  function updatestatus() {
    return status;
  }
})();
```

I do not know if this is the right method to update status and return

Comment: The return value of the `setInterval` callback is ignored. Not sure what you expect to happen with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code that actually sets the status is finished before your `setInterval` even begins. Additionally, I'm not sure what you are trying to do with the variable `status` as your `setInterval` function only returns and it never actually used.

Maybe try something like this:

```js
(function () {
    var status = "Working...";
    const interval = setInterval( () => {
        console.log(status);
    }, 100);
    if (document.getElementById("label_s").style.display === 'none') {
        status = "Stopped."
    } else {
        status = "Reading label_s...";
        var labels = document.getElementById("label_s").innerHTML;
    }
    if (document.getElementById("label_d").style.display === 'none') {
        status = "Stopped."
    } else {
        status = "Reading label_d...";
        var labelsd = document.getElementById("label_d").innerHTML;
    }
    status = "Stopping";
    // Done. Clear the interval
    clearInterval(interval);
})();
```

There's some fundamental code missing so It's not clear what the exact output is supposed to be. However, fixing those two issues may get you closer to where you're trying to get.

Comment: How can I return this updated value? Without console.log() like a return status inside function()

Comment: I think `setInterval` is probably the wrong thing you want. Are you trying to develop a function that gets the current status or are you trying to do something with that status every 100ms?

Comment: I need the two only in a function (show and update and show ...), I just do not know if it's possible